# Help me write code for matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix, core-language

I am beginner in Mathematica. I am trying to write code for multiplicating two 2x 2 matrices. It produces an error. Can you tell me what is the problem?

```
matmult[a_,b_]:= 
u=Table[0,{2},{2}];
Do[u[[i,j]]=a[[i]].Transpose[b][[j]],{i,1,2},{j,1,2}];
u
```

Comment: Sory, m and n are a and b!

Comment: You need parenthesis `matmult[a_,b_]:=(u=...;u)`

Comment: You can edit your own question to fix m and n to a and b.

Comment: Umm, since you are using Mathematica, how about `a.b`? Also check this [reference/tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MultiplyingVectorsAndMatrices.html.en).

Comment: Is it that you need to multiply two matrices together, or that you need to demonstrate an algorithm to multiply two matrices together?

Comment: Matrix multiplication is already defined in Mathematica. Look at [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Coolwater! It works.

Answer (score 1):

Matrix multiplication is already defined in Mathematica as a generalized dot product. Look at [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) in the documentation.

However, if for some scholastic reason you must limit `Dot` to vectors, then you should write your code as:

```
matmult[a_, b_] := Table[a[[i]].Transpose[b][[j]], {i, 2}, {j, 2}]
```

No need for introducing an auxiliary variable such as `u` and no need for parentheses.

```
Clear[a, b, c, d , r, s, t, u]
matmult[{{a, b}, {c, d}} , {{r, s}, {t, u}}]
```

> `{{a r + b t, a s + b u}, {c r + d t, c s + d u}}`